# How to integrate $(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 + 1)$?

Tags: integration

I have gone until separating $(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 + 1)$ into $x^2/(x^2 + 1)$ - $1/(x^2 + 1)$. The latter fraction I can substitute by $\tan u$, but how to solve the first fraction and how does it all come together?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\int\frac{x^2-1}{1+x^2}dx=\int\left(1-\frac2{1+x^2}\right)dx=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \frac{x^2 -1}{x^2 + 1} dx = \int \frac{x^2 +1 - 1 - 1}{x^2+1}dx = \int dx - 2 \int\frac{dx}{x^2+1} = x - 2 \arctan x + C $$

Comment: Ick. I used to HATE problems like this in baby calculus and physics.

Comment: why? they are nice